# Astro Build Error, Markdown with Typescript

Tags: typescript, build, config, astrojs

When I try to build my Astro Project with `npm run build` or go to one of my markdown pages after running: `npm run dev` I run into this Error:

```
> astro-blog-template@0.0.1 build
> astro build

17:42:55 [build] output target: static   
17:42:55 [build] Collecting build info...
17:42:55 [build] Completed in 47ms.
17:42:55 [build] Building static entrypoints...
[vite:esbuild] failed to resolve "extends":"astro/tsconfigs/strict" in C:\Users\felix\documents\programmieren\hhh\tsconfig.json
file: C:/Users/felix/documents/programmieren/hhh/src/utils/getPostData.ts
 error   failed to resolve "extends":"astro/tsconfigs/strict" in C:\Users\felix\documents\programmieren\hhh\tsconfig.json
  File:
    C:/Users/felix/documents/programmieren/hhh/src/utils/getPostData.ts
  Stacktrace:
    at resolveExtends (file:///C:/Users/felix/Documents/Programmieren/hhh/node_modules/astro/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5cb728cb.js:13162:9)    
    at parseExtends (file:///C:/Users/felix/Documents/Programmieren/hhh/node_modules/astro/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5cb728cb.js:13135:34)     
    at parse$g (file:///C:/Users/felix/Documents/Programmieren/hhh/node_modules/astro/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5cb728cb.js:13086:24)
js:13557:24)
    at async transformWithEsbuild (file:///C:/Users/felix/Documents/Programmieren/hhh/node_modules/astro/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5cb728cb.js:13280:36)
    at async Object.transform (file:///C:/Users/felix/Documents/Programmieren/hhh/node_modules/astro/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5cb728cb.js:13379:32)
    at async transform (file:///C:/Users/felix/Documents/Programmieren/hhh/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:21911:16)
    at async ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (file:///C:/Users/felix/Documents/Programmieren/hhh/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:22136:30)
```

There seems to be an issue with the tsconfig.json file so I tried to switch the tsconfig.json file from:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Enable top-level await, and other modern ESM features.
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    // Enable node-style module resolution, for things like npm package imports.
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    // Enable JSON imports.
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    // Enable stricter transpilation for better output.
    "isolatedModules": true,
    // Astro will directly run your TypeScript code, no transpilation needed.
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "extends": "astro/tsconfigs/strict"
}
```

to:

```js
{
  "extends": "astro/tsconfigs/strict",
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "**/*.jsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "studio"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["astro/client"],
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    // Enable node-style module resolution, for things like npm package imports.
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    // Enable JSON imports.
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    // Enable stricter transpilation for better output.
    "isolatedModules": true,
    // Astro will directly run your TypeScript code, no transpilation needed.
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": "/",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@layouts/*": ["src/layouts/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

When running `npm run dev` this seems to fix the problem (sometimes?), but with `npm run build` it still throws the above error. I am quite new to Typescript so a thorough explaination is apprechiated. The projects source is found on [github](https://github.com/felkru/hhh).
How can I remove this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as the compiler said, there was a problem with `"extends": "astro/tsconfigs/strict"`. It could not locate the resource. I do not know why. I fixed it by directly replacing the former `tsconfig.json` file with the file it should have extended and manually adding the properties not already contained. You can refer to their [typescript documentation page](https://docs.astro.build/de/guides/typescript/) on how their tsbuild.json files work. The files were found on their [GitHub](https://github.com/withastro/astro/tree/main/packages/astro/tsconfigs).